# Dropdown contact form - changing the background image on the button once the form has animated down

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a dropdown contact form and you can view the code below:

http://jsfiddle.net/VtQbE/4/

Basically at current there is a black button that when is pressed it triggers the jquery to drop down and display the form.

What I want to do is have a background image showing a "down arrow" and then after the button is pressed and it drops down to display the form, I want an "up arrow"

It seems so simple but I have not found a way to do this whilst messing around with it.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Please fix your jsFiddle example.

Comment: fixed. sorry about that, it didnt update my last edits for some reason but its working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a arrow down background image to `<div id="contactLink"></div>` like this `<div id="contactLink" style="background:url('arrowdown.png')"></div>` then in your function

```
$("#contactLink").click(function(){
   if ($("#contactForm").is(":hidden")){
      $("#contactForm").slideDown("slow");
      $('#contactLink').css('background', "url('arrowup.png')");
   }else{
      $("#contactForm").slideUp("slow");
      $('#contactLink').css('background', "url('arrowdown.png')");
   }
});
```

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/bq6tN/ but with an image background. You can add a img inside contactlink if you want

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/VtQbE/6/ Here it is, hope it's what you need :)

I used images found on the web, just use your own. You can also adds some css,if you want to position the images somewhere else, within the black bar.